# How do I make a basic regression prediction?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

At the end of a basic regression tutorial, there is no explanation on how to get a Y value or prediction out from an input.

The tutorial is a basic regression tutorial from TensorFlow

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/keras/basic_regression.ipynb

To start with I just have 2 columns Time and Sales.

I have used my own data and want to predict future sales by the month. I have turned the time into numeric values. If I have data for 30 months I would like to predict month 31 - 35.

I have found that the sets.run function will give results but I don't know how in my case.

```
column_names = ['Time','Sales']
```

and

```
model = keras.Sequential
```

My data works with the tutorial. But I don't know how to get the results out of it?

The following code works and creates a prediction against the actual result line.

```
test_predictions = model.predict(normed_test_data).flatten()

plt.scatter(test_labels, test_predictions)
plt.xlabel('True Values [Sales]')
plt.ylabel('Predictions [Sales]')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis('square')
plt.xlim([0,plt.xlim()[1]])
plt.ylim([0,plt.ylim()[1]])
_ = plt.plot([-100, 100], [-100, 100])
```

I would like to provide input as the month and get the prediction.

Comment: Are `time` and `month` different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data you want to use in your prediction is already normalized then it's just a case of calling the `model.predict` function with the same shape input parameters as was used in training.

So for the example in the tutorial, I can do something like:

```
test = [{
    "Cylinders": -0.84,
    "Displacement": -1.0,
    "Horsepower": -0.7,
    "Weight": -1.1,
    "Acceleration": 0.5,
    "Model Year": -0.5,
    "USA": 0.77,
    "Europe": -0.465148,
    "Japan": -0.495225
},{
    "Cylinders": -0.54,
    "Displacement": -2.0,
    "Horsepower": -0.1,
    "Weight": -1.1,
    "Acceleration": 0.5,
    "Model Year": -0.5,
    "USA": 0.77,
    "Europe": -0.465148,
    "Japan": -0.495225
}]

testdf = pd.DataFrame(test)
preds = model.predict(testdf)
```

If your own model just takes Time and Sales then I guess you could do:

```
test = [{
    "Time": -0.7,
    "Sales": 0.1
},{
    "Time": 1,
    "Sales": 1.1
}]

testdf = pd.DataFrame(test)
preds = model.predict(testdf)
```

If the data you want to use in your prediction is not already normalised then you'll need to call the `norm` function first. Something like this:

```
test = [{
    "Cylinders": 6,
    "Displacement": 150,
    "Horsepower": 150,
    "Weight": 1200,
    "Acceleration": 45,
    "Model Year": 75,
    "USA": 0,
    "Europe": 1,
    "Japan": 0
},{
    "Cylinders": 4,
    "Displacement": 90,
    "Horsepower": 75,
    "Weight": 1200,
    "Acceleration": 15,
    "Model Year": 77,
    "USA": 1,
    "Europe": 0,
    "Japan": 0
}]

testdf = pd.DataFrame(test)
normed = norm(testdf)
preds = model.predict(normed)
```

I should say though that the problem you have described ("Sales" and "Month") sounds like a time series model rather than a regression problem so perhaps the regression tutorial isn't best for this type of problem but without knowing more it's impossible to say

Comment: Hi @Stewart_R Thanks for answering. The model worked. I have gone on to build a time series model. I am brand new to machine learning and yet again the tutorial stops at the RMSE - I have tried applying your suggestion. to this model but get stuck yet again. This one turns kit into 3 dimensions - however once I match my input to the array shape I get errors. I tried using test = [{{
  30
}}]

X = numpy.array(test)
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1]))

preds = model.predict(X)     Is there an easy way to use the model.predict function? Or should I post a new question?